# What exactly is the watch suppose to be keeping track of in episode 10?

Tags: cowboy-bebop

In episode 10, "Ganymede Elegy", the watch has a dial that has numerals 1 - 15 on it (it figures prominently in the story's plot).

[image: the watch]

It takes 7.15 Earth days (around 172 Earth hours) for Ganymede to orbit Jupiter and the orbit is synchronous. Even if you artificially give Ganymede a 15 or 30 hour day, the numbers don't add up to a complete planetary rotation.

So, what exactly is the watch suppose to be keeping track of?

Comment: ["Jet's pocket watch goes up to 15 "hours", suggesting a different time scale on Ganymede."](http://www.tv.com/shows/cowboy-bebop/trivia/) also https://www.reddit.com/r/cowboybebop/comments/1lslvc/cowboy_bebop_rewatch_and_discussion_session_10/cc34oiq/